# Input Simulator TextEntry - Simulates Inline

Tags: c#, input, text, multiline, inputsimulator

I use Input Simulator in my C# Form Application.

(I use serial port to execute codes)

When i execute

```
InputSimulator.Keyboard.TextEntry(textbox.text);
```

on Notepad, it simulates perfectly.

But not on any other programs such as Gmail....

How can i make it multiline?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: How does the string sent to TextEntry method looks like?

Comment: Multiline richtextbox text

Comment: How STRING looks like, I know where it comes from. What characters does it contain? Does it contain line terminators?

Comment: No it's plain text. And when i try to replace "@" or something to "/r/n" it doesn't do anything.